# Does the linux kernel keyring store keys on disk?

Tags: linux, archlinux, ecryptfs

I'm trying to learn a bit about the linux kernel keyring (as background for using ecryptfs).  Does the kernel keyring store keys somewhere on disk, or does it get reinitiailized programmatically everytime the sytem is booted?

I've looked at the man pages and archlinux documentation on encryption but haven't found the answer.  If there's other documentation on the kernel keyring, I'd like to know.

If the kernel keyring does store keys on the disk, where does it put the files?

thanks

PS Excuse the rather broad choice of tags: stackoverflow does not have tags for 'keyring' or 'kernel keyring'

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about the design and implementation of Unix/Linux. unix.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this.

Comment: `TPM` or `Trusted Platform Module` allows RSA keypair to be stored on chip.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Pc  use the [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (Trusted Platform Module :It’s a chip on your computer’s motherboard) , an encryption key is  stored in the TPM

[image]

An old PC (without a TPM) , It has no way to store encryption keys in a TPM , that means it has to store its encryption keys on the hard drive